# How to strip text with javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm a newbie with javascript and I want to strip text. I have string that looks like this

```
<iframe src="http://embed.videokoo.com/61YVek?client_file_id=390856&width=720&height=480" style="width:720px;height:480px;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;"></iframe>
```

I want to strip everything except the url which the final output should look like this:

```
http://embed.videokoo.com/61YVek?client_file_id=390856
```

How can I do this?

Comment: http://regexpal.com/ is useful for this :-)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp

Comment: We could use more information. Will the URL always be for `embed.videokoo.com`? Are you doing this in the browser? Is the iframe an element on the page, or is it part of a string?

Comment: @meagar yes the url will always be embed.videokoo.com with different digits. Yes this is from a browser. It's just text in a textarea box so it's not a iframe element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution, given that your `<iframe...>` is actually a string coming from a `<textarea>` and that you're always trying to match the same `http://embed.videokoo.com...` URL, isn't to "strip" the string, but to match a *substring* with a regular expression:

```js
var str = '<iframe src="http://embed.videokoo.com/61YVek?client_file_id=390856&width=720&height=480" style="width:720px;height:480px;border:0;margin:0;padding:0;"></iframe>'
    
var substring = str.match(/http:\/\/embed.videokoo.com\/\w+\?client_file_id=\d+/)

document.write(substring);
```